# The distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not induced by an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

We define the distance like $d(v,w)$ = {the number of different entries} and I'm supposed to prove that this is not induced by an inner product. So far what I´ve done is use the parallelogram law to prove a norm is not induced by an inner product, however I'm not sure I can do the same for the distance.

Comment: How are you going to define the distance if you have an inner product?

Comment: Your distance function is bounded but inner products are bilinear.

Comment: In order for a distance to be induced by an inner product, it also has to be induced by a norm (specifically, the norm $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$). For this question, it's simplest to show that this distance is not induced by a norm.